# Use different regex engine for different use cases/plugins

Tags: regular-expression

By default `re=0`, however I'm running into those issues:

- `re=1` makes [ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) much faster
- `re=2` makes [vim-jsx-pretty](https://github.com/MaxMEllon/vim-jsx-pretty) much faster

And somehow `re=0` can't seem to get those right for me.

Is there a way to set different `re` values for different plugins w/o having to fork anything (I understand `\%#=0`, `\%#=1`, `\%#=2` could be used to force a particular engine in a particular place, see `:help two-engines`).

Edit: `vim-jsx-pretty` isn't the issue, thank to `:syntime on` I can see:

```
  TOTAL      COUNT  MATCH   SLOWEST     AVERAGE   NAME               PATTERN
  1.995582   11     0       1.995576    0.181417  typescriptArrowFuncDef (\(\_s*[a-zA-Z\$_\[.]\_[^)]*\)*)\s*=>
```

Which comes [from Vim itself](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/typescriptcommon.vim#L1902-L1908).

Edit 2: removing https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim did fix perf issues.